# How do I convert a Worksheet variable to a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, excel

I read a table from an excel file in the following method :

```
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
inputdata=workbook.Worksheets("Values").Select() ## Select Worksheet by Name     
ws1 = workbook.Worksheets("Values") #workbook.ActiveSheet.Name
```

when I type ws in command prompt I get

```
System.__ComObject
```

I can access the table in ws1 by :

```
print ws1.Cells(i,j).Value2
```

But I need to have the table in the following way :

```
table =[[row1], [row2],[row3],...]
```

doing dir(ws1) I have

> ['ACTIVATE', 'Activate', 'Application', 'Arcs', 'AutoFilter',
>   'AutoFilterMode', 'BEFOREDELETE', 'BEFOREDOUBLECLICK',
>   'BEFORERIGHTCLICK', 'Buttons', 'CALCULATE', 'CHANGE', 'Calculate',
>   'Cells', 'ChartObjects', 'CheckBoxes', 'CheckSpelling',
>   'CircleInvalid', 'CircularReference', 'ClearArrows', 'ClearCircles',
>   'CodeName', 'Columns', 'Comments', 'CommentsThreaded',
>   'ConsolidationFunction', 'ConsolidationOptions',
>   'ConsolidationSources', 'Copy', 'CreateObjRef', 'Creator',
>   'CustomProperties', 'DEACTIVATE', 'Delete',
>   'DisplayAutomaticPageBreaks', 'DisplayPageBreaks',
>   'DisplayRightToLeft', 'DrawingObjects', 'Drawings', 'DropDowns',
>   'EnableAutoFilter', 'EnableCalculation',
>   'EnableFormatConditionsCalculation', 'EnableOutlining',
>   'EnablePivotTable', 'EnableSelection', 'Equals', 'Evaluate',
>   'ExportAsFixedFormat', 'FOLLOWHYPERLINK', 'FilterMode', 'GetHashCode',
>   'GetLifetimeService', 'GetType', 'GroupBoxes', 'GroupObjects',
>   'HPageBreaks', 'Hyperlinks', 'Index', 'InitializeLifetimeService',
>   'LENSGALLERYRENDERCOMPLETE', 'Labels', 'Lines', 'ListBoxes',
>   'ListObjects', 'MailEnvelope', 'MemberwiseClone', 'Move', 'Name',
>   'Names', 'Next', 'OLEObjects', 'OnCalculate', 'OnData',
>   'OnDoubleClick', 'OnEntry', 'OnSheetActivate', 'OnSheetDeactivate',
>   'OptionButtons', 'Outline', 'Ovals', 'PIVOTTABLEAFTERVALUECHANGE',
>   'PIVOTTABLEBEFOREALLOCATECHANGES', 'PIVOTTABLEBEFORECOMMITCHANGES',
>   'PIVOTTABLEBEFOREDISCARDCHANGES', 'PIVOTTABLECHANGESYNC',
>   'PIVOTTABLEUPDATE', 'PageSetup', 'Parent', 'Paste', 'PasteSpecial',
>   'Pictures', 'PivotTableWizard', 'PivotTables', 'Previous', 'PrintOut',
>   'PrintPreview', 'PrintedCommentPages', 'Protect', 'ProtectContents',
>   'ProtectDrawingObjects', 'ProtectScenarios', 'Protection',
>   'ProtectionMode', 'QueryTables', 'Range', 'Rectangles',
>   'ReferenceEquals', 'ResetAllPageBreaks', 'Rows', 'SELECTIONCHANGE',
>   'SaveAs', 'Scenarios', 'Scripts', 'ScrollArea', 'ScrollBars',
>   'Select', 'SetBackgroundPicture', 'Shapes', 'ShowAllData',
>   'ShowDataForm', 'SmartTags', 'Sort', 'Spinners', 'StandardHeight',
>   'StandardWidth', 'TABLEUPDATE', 'Tab', 'TextBoxes', 'ToString',
>   'TransitionExpEval', 'TransitionFormEntry', 'Type', 'Unprotect',
>   'UsedRange', 'VPageBreaks', 'Visible', 'XmlDataQuery', 'XmlMapQuery',
>   '_AutoFilter', '_CheckSpelling', '_CodeName', '_DisplayRightToLeft',
>   '_Evaluate', '_ExportAsFixedFormat', '_PasteSpecial', '_PrintOut',
>   '_Protect', '_SaveAs', '_Sort', '**PrintOut', '__SaveAs', '__class**',
>   '**delattr**', '**doc**', '**format**', '**getattribute**',
>   '**hash**', '**init**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**',
>   '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
>   '**subclasshook**']

I tried this loop but it adds the values excessive times

```
innerlist=[];
mygrid=[]
for i in range(2,14):
    for j in range(2,22):
        innerlist.append(ws1.Cells(i,j).Value2)
    mygrid.append(innerlist)
```

just one point : I am using python add in in another software, so I can not use libraries like pandas etc. I could just use simple loops and algorithms

Comment: Are you on Windows? Are you on python 2? I can't find the excel module. Did you try writing a loop?

Comment: yes I am on Windows, and yes I suppose it's Python2.7. yes I did something like 
mygrid=[]
for i in range(1,14):
    for j in range(1,22):
        mygrid[i,j]=ws1.Cells(i,j).Value2

Comment: So, I am on Linux with Python3.7 (hope your aware that python2 has been officially retired). Anyway, I don't know what attributes you have available on ws1, did you read through dir(ws1) for any attributes that might make this easier? If not, then the loop method is going to be your only way of extracting the needed information. Was there a problem in creating mygrid?

Comment: @BobbyOcean thank you very much, I updated my question with it

Comment: Sir, you need to read through the documentation of these functions. Are you in ipython? If so, run "ws1.Rows?", how does that function work, does it sound useful? QueryTables? How about ToString? If your not in ipython, print the doc string. print(ws1.Rows.__doc__). Do you have a link to the modules documentation? Where does it exist online?

Comment: @BobbyOcean dear Bobby, yes it's iPython , I tried ws1.Columns.Column but it gives me the integer number of 1 ! that's all. its chm help file might not be on internet , cause it's for spaceclaim.

Comment: I added the loop I tried, it works but it adds the values too many times

Comment: ok resolved, I had to empty the innerlist